# JQuery: How to Extract Element and insert Text/Element before the extracted Element?

Tags: jquery, insert

Hallo,

I would appreciate your advice. Given the following snippet:

```
<div id="parent"><div id="child">ChildText<span id="subchildtext"><b>SubChildText</b></span></div></div>
```

I want to:

1. Extract the span Element
   ==>`var span = $("#child").find("span");`
2. Prepend some Text ("foobar") and a new HTML element ("`<b>`foorbarbold`</b>`)
   ==>`span.insertBefore("foobar<b>foobarbold</b>")`
3. Insert that new Element "into" the Parent (ID=PArent element)
   ==> `$("#parent").html(span);`

The result should be: `<div id="parent">foobar<b>foobarbold</b><span id="subchildtext"><b>SubChildText</b></span></div>`

But that doesnt work. I am not able to insert the new content to the extracted element. How could I accomplish this?

Thank you very much!
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`$('#parent').html($('#subchildtext')).prepend('foobar<b>foodbarbold</b>');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jQuery, but here is how you do it with javascript

```
var span = document.getElementById("subchildtext");
var newBold = document.createElement("b");
newBold.appendChild(document.createTextNode("foobarbold"));
span.insertBefore(newBold, span.firstChild);
span.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("foobar"), span.firstChild)
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the html of the parent, try this:

```
$("#parent").html(span.html());
```

But you may find you need to remove the original, in which case you may need.

```
span.remove();
```

However, the following may work for you in one line (I've not tested it, but its on the right lines)

```
span.appendTo("#parent");
```

Or if you want it at the start

```
span.preprendTo("#parent");
```

Some links for you as well:

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove

Hope this helps